# How do I plot PGSQL queries onto google maps?

Tags: json, postgresql, google-maps

So i am trying to learn how to store pgsql queries on a google map. So my database contains two json columns for the lat/long. I have the slightest idea of how to query json from pgsql and display it on google maps. Can someone give me some tutorials or can someone give me some insight on getting this done?

Comment: This isnt on-topic for this [**forum**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), is too broad. You should try google first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do that is to choose a "backend" programming language, like python, php and write a little program on a web server like Apache, which connects to the database and queries the data when the browser asks for it.

You also should have the "user interface" part, which is html/css/javascript what displays this in your browser.

There are many such projects, you can use google, github to find open source projects for it, or use stackoverflow to find answers for specific parts of it.